# Spring Security 3.2 + GWT

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

We (my team) are currently developing a POC; to build a front-end with GWT but uses Spring for the back-end.
So far, we have not encountered any significant problems integrating the two.

However, when we decided to use Spring Security 3.2 (just recently released), we encountered some issues with the security headers.
After some research, we discovered that it has to do with click jacking prevention (the X-Frame-Options).

Our approach is as follows.
The login page is not part of GWT but simple page (e.g., login.jsp).
Once authentication is successful, it should change to the GWT start page.

However, with the default security headers, once an authentication succeeds, only a blank page is shown.
For now, we simply disabled the security headers as follows (using Spring Java Configuration).

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.headers().disable();
}
```

With the security headers disabled, the GWT page shows up correctly.
We would prefer keep the security headers enabled.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Updated: In the web.xml file, we use the following.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I tested it with my `GWT` app and `Spring Security 3.2` and it works fine. How do you redirect to the GWT page ? Do you use Spring's internal redirect mechanism ?

Comment: Yes, we use Spring's out-of-the-box redirect mechanism. I updated the question as well.

Comment: I use the same `DelegatingFilterProxy` and the redirect works just fine. Which Linker do you use in `GWT` ? Try to use the `xsiframe Linker` instead the standard (`xs`) one.

Comment: The default one: the `IFrameLinker`

Comment: Try to use `xsiframe` Linker.

Comment: That works. Thank you. In addition, we did another experiment using the StockWatcher tutorial. We converted it to use `Spring4Gwt` so the server side is Spring based. We did not encounter the redirect problem with this example. The difference between our POC and the tutorial is we use `UIBinder` and `RootLayoutPanel`.